# JavaScript condition style "A && B || C" vs "A ? B : C"

Tags: javascript, syntax

Is there anything **wrong** on using JavaScript condition style

```
cond1 && cond2
cond1 && cond2 || cond3
cond1 && cond2 || cond3 || cond4
```

instead of

```
cond1 ? cond2 : cond3
```

?

The first condition style has shorter syntax and performance benefit, while it might mislead someone thinking that

```
document.getElementById("a") && 1 // null or 1
```

returns the same result as

```
document.getElementById("a") ? 1 : undefined // undefined or 1
```

Your thoughts?

Comment: Can you please give us an example?

Comment: For me, the first one is better, I can't see the benefit of returning `undefined`, it's something you have to do, but don't really want. What you want is this senetence `document.getElementById("a") ? 1` but it isn't a legal sentence... so you have to include `undefined`

Comment: In general use any *performance benefit* is so incredibly negligible its not worth considering

Comment: Personally I wouldn't worry about shortness of syntax or performance benefits - instead write code that is easy to understand.  The optimisations performed by JS engines these days are excellent, but unreadable code hasn't got any easier to maintain.

Comment: Leaving aside the difference in what they do and mean, why would you think that the ternary operator has poorer performance? Also, `cond1 && cond2 || cond3` is actually longer than the ternary version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are right `A && B || C` and `A ? B : C`. Use most suitable to case and used code style pattern.
In most cases `?` will cause unnecessary code execute, like 2x executed `a()` in  `a() ? a() : b()` vs 1x with `a() || b()`. `||` wins!

For example

```
C || A + B  // is better than C ? C : A + B
C + A || B  // is better than C + A ? C + A : B
A() || B() || C // is better than A() ? A() : (B() ? B() : C)
A ? B : C || D || A   // is better than A ? B : (C ? C : (D ? D : A))
A === 1 || B < C || D // is better than A === 1 ? true : (B < C ? true : D)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's very wrong. They've got different results for the case `cond1 = true`, `cond2 = false`, `cond3 = true`.

> it might mislead someone thinking that `document.getElementById("a") && 1` - `null` or `1` - returns the same result as `document.getElementById("a") ? 1 : undefined` - `undefined` or `1`

Yes, as you state they're not the same.

Comment: Don't stick to mentioned cases, but think for all possible variations/cases.

Comment: @Binyamin: Of course, there are cases where both could be suitable, but no, in general they are not the same and you should choose the one that you need.